# Why does cross gcc invoke native 'as'?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, cross-compiling

I am in the process of building the ps2 (playstation 2) toolchain for OSX using an existing script which worked fine for Linux/Windows in the past but has always been troublesome on OSX.

The problem I am facing right now is that I get to a point where cross gcc is apparently invoking the native 'as' instead of the existing cross 'as':

> ee-gcc -B/Users/gilligan/ps2toolchain/build/newlib-1.10.0/build-ee/ee/newlib/ -isystem /Users/gilligan/ps2toolchain/build/newlib-1.10.0/build-ee/ee/newlib/targ-include -isystem /Users/gilligan/ps2toolchain/build/newlib-1.10.0/newlib/libc/include -DPACKAGE=\"newlib\" -DVERSION=\"1.10.0\"  -I. -I../../../../../newlib/libc/stdlib  -O2 -DMALLOC_ALIGNMENT=16 -DMISSING_SYSCALL_NAMES -I../../targ-include -I../../../../../newlib/libc/../libc/include -fno-builtin    -G0  -g -c ../../../../../newlib/libc/stdlib/__adjust.c
>   ee-gcc -B/Users/gilligan/ps2toolchain/build/newlib-1.10.0/build-ee/ee/newlib/ -isystem /Users/gilligan/ps2toolchain/build/newlib-1.10.0/build-ee/ee/newlib/targ-include -isystem /Users/gilligan/ps2toolchain/build/newlib-1.10.0/newlib/libc/include -DPACKAGE=\"newlib\" -DVERSION=\"1.10.0\"  -I. -I../../../../../newlib/libc/stdlib  -O2 -DMALLOC_ALIGNMENT=16 -DMISSING_SYSCALL_NAMES -I../../targ-include -I../../../../../newlib/libc/../libc/include -fno-builtin    -G0  -g -c ../../../../../newlib/libc/stdlib/__exp10.c
>   FATAL:/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'G' flag!
>   make[3]: *** [__exp10.o] Error 1
>   make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>   FATAL:/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'G' flag!
>   make[3]: *** [__adjust.o] Error 1
>   make[2]:**  [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]:  **[all-recursive] Error 1
>   make: *** [all-target-newlib] Error 2

The thing to notice here (sorry not very readable) is that **ee-gcc** is invoking 'as' from **/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as** i.e the system native one instead of ee-as. How can this be ?

Checking the output of '*ee-gcc -print-search-dirs*' I can see that ee-as is indeed in one of the specified paths and I checked that it is executable.

Might be hard to say anything about this without access to all data but maybe someone has an idea what I can look for - I don't understand how ee-gcc resolves its assembler to be the native one. How does the assembler binary selection work ?

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the input but i'm afraid the whole thing is more broken than initially anticipated. Now gcc (llvm-gcc-4.2) is segfaulting while processing libgcc2.c

> /Users/gilligan/Development/ps2dev/ps2toolchain/build/gcc-3.2.2/build-ee-stage1/gcc/xgcc -B/Users/gilligan/Development/ps2dev/ps2toolchain/build/gcc-3.2.2/build-ee-stage1/gcc/ -B/usr/local/ps2dev/ee//ee/bin/ -B/usr/local/ps2dev/ee//ee/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/ps2dev/ee//ee/include -O2  -DIN_GCC -DCROSS_COMPILE   -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -isystem ./include  -G 0 -g  -DIN_LIBGCC2 -D__GCC_FLOAT_NOT_NEEDED -Dinhibit_libc -I. -I. -I../../gcc -I../../gcc/. -I../../gcc/config -I../../gcc/../include  -DL_muldi3 -c ../../gcc/libgcc2.c -o libgcc/./_muldi3.o
>   In file included from ../../gcc/libgcc2.c:44:
>   ../../gcc/libgcc2.h:242: internal error: Segmentation fault: 11
>   Please submit a full bug report,
>   with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>   See  for instructions.
>   make[2]: *** [libgcc/./_muldi3.o] Error 1
>   make[1]:**  [libgcc.a] Error 2
>   make: ** [all-gcc] Error 2

I started to google for related bug reports/patches but so far no dice. Guess i'm about to give in. Thanks again for the input.

Comment: Did you try to force "`AS=ee-as make`"?

Answer (score 2):

Assembler path resolving is AFAIK in machine spec

```
 gcc -dumpspecs
```

and look to `*invoke_as:` section

You can override specs with `-specs=` option.

Comment: The `-B` on the command line should override the search path for compiler/assembler/linker binaries...

Comment: R.., But which name does gcc try?

Comment: I believe it searches for both `as` and the target-name-prefixed version in the paths given with `-B`.