# g++: No Such Instruction with AVX

Tags: macos, g++, macports, avx

When I compiled a program I was writing in C++ (for the latest Macbook pro, which of course supports the AVX instruction set), I got the following errors. I am using the latest release of g++ obtained from Macports. Do you have any ideas as to what I can do to fix the error without restricting the instruction sets available to the compiler? Is there any package in particular that I should try to update?

```
g++-mp-4.7 -std=c++11 -Wall -Ofast -march=native -fno-rtti src/raw_to_json.cpp -o bin/raw_to_json.bin
/var/folders/83/tjczqmxn1y9166m642_rxdlw0000gn/T//cc0hIx0w.s:1831:no such instruction: `vpxor %xmm0, %xmm0,%xmm0'
/var/folders/83/tjczqmxn1y9166m642_rxdlw0000gn/T//cc0hIx0w.s:1847:no such instruction: `vmovdqa %xmm0, 96(%rsp)'
/var/folders/83/tjczqmxn1y9166m642_rxdlw0000gn/T//cc0hIx0w.s:1848:no such instruction: `vmovdqa %xmm0, 112(%rsp)'
/var/folders/83/tjczqmxn1y9166m642_rxdlw0000gn/T//cc0hIx0w.s:1849:no such instruction: `vmovdqa %xmm0, 128(%rsp)'
/var/folders/83/tjczqmxn1y9166m642_rxdlw0000gn/T//cc0hIx0w.s:1850:no such instruction: `vmovdqa %xmm0, 144(%rsp)'
/var/folders/83/tjczqmxn1y9166m642_rxdlw0000gn/T//cc0hIx0w.s:1851:no such instruction: `vmovdqa %xmm0, 160(%rsp)'
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use AVX/pclmulqdq on Mac OS X Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840207/how-to-use-avx-pclmulqdq-on-mac-os-x-lion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed thanks to Conrado PLG's answer to his own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840207/how-to-use-avx-pclmulqdq-on-mac-os-x-lion). In short, I had to do the following:

1. Move or otherwise get rid of the old `as`, found at `/opt/local/bin/../local/libexec/as/x86_64/as`.
2. Copy the script by Vincent Habchi, found [here](https://gist.github.com/xianyi/2957847), to `/opt/local/bin/../local/libexec/as/x86_64/as`.
3. `sudo chmod +x` the script.

Note that there may some performance degradation, due to the fact that calling the assembler requires going through a shell script first.

Comment: Note also that the clang compiler that comes with Xcode also supports AVX.

Answer (score 6):

A simpler solution that fixed this problem for me was adding `-Wa,-q` to the compiler flags. From the man pages for `as` (version 1.38):

-q
Use  the  clang(1)  integrated  assembler instead of the GNU based system assembler.