# How to compile C code that #includes C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I have to compile generated C code that `#include`s C++ headers and it get it to work on Linux, OS X and Windows. I put the `#include`s myself to be able to interact with C++ code from it.

The C code however is such that a strict compiler would catch errors that *could* be treated as warnings. I want to pass these off as warnings as most of this is generated code which I don't have control over.

Here are my attempts to compile it (I use `CMake`, btw):

(I use these flags: `-Wno-write-strings -Wno-error -fpermissive`)

- Treat the entire project as C++ code: works on Linux (with `g++`) but on OS X I get:

With `Clang`:

```
error: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'const char *'
```

With `g++`:

```
/var/folders/hf/5dbkbqrx5p3bmnpdqqy4wgpr0000gn/T//ccvMHo2S.s:18:no such instruction: `vmovdqa LC0(%rip), %xmm3'
/var/folders/hf/5dbkbqrx5p3bmnpdqqy4wgpr0000gn/T//ccvMHo2S.s:19:no such instruction: `vmovdqa LC1(%rip), %xmm2'
/var/folders/hf/5dbkbqrx5p3bmnpdqqy4wgpr0000gn/T//ccvMHo2S.s:20:no such instruction: `vmovdqu (%rsi), %xmm7'
/var/folders/hf/5dbkbqrx5p3bmnpdqqy4wgpr0000gn/T//ccvMHo2S.s:21:no such instruction: `vmovdqu 16(%rsi), %xmm8'
/var/folders/hf/5dbkbqrx5p3bmnpdqqy4wgpr0000gn/T//ccvMHo2S.s:22:no such instruction: `vmovdqa LC2(%rip), %xmm1'
/var/folders/hf/5dbkbqrx5p3bmnpdqqy4wgpr0000gn/T//ccvMHo2S.s:23:no such instruction: `vpshufb %xmm3, %xmm7,%xmm6'
```

- Treat C code as C code:

Doesn't find `<atomic>`

```
 fatal error: atomic: No such file or directory
 #include <atomic>
```

- Use `-Wa -q` flags as per this answer:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19339870/3684931 (I made a mistake there. It should have been `-Wa, -q`)

Flag becomes invalid.

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-q'
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
```

- Use `-Wa,-q` flags as per this answer:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19339870/3684931

Flag is still invalid.

```
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
clang: error: unsupported argument '-q' to option 'Wa,'
```

How do I go about building this?

Comment: Your best solution is to compile all files as if they were C++.  One problem is name mangling.

Comment: Go the hard way: Wrap the C++ in a library using C++ and exposing C functions, only.

Comment: You will have to ensure that the generated C code is such that it is acceptable to a C++ compiler, because if you include C++ headers, you must use a C++ to do the compilation.  The error from `clang` tells you that you are (probably) assigning a string literal to a `char *` instead of a `const char *`, which C++ does not allow.  The mismatched assembler is puzzling; it may mean your GCC installation is broken.

Comment: Note that SO 19339870 said "Use `-Wa,-q`" where the comma is a key part of the syntax.  It means 'pass the `-q` flag to the assembler'.  What you tried passed nothing to the assembler and then tried to tell `clang` to use the `-q` flag, which it didn't recognize.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how GENERATED C code includes C++ headers? Surely the C code generator will not have generated those C++ includes? The reason I ask this, is that is seems that you at least manually modified the generated code to include those headers. So why not modify it a bit more to be acceptable as a subset of C++ and be compiled by a C++ compiler?

Comment: @jacdeh, my bad. I put them myself to be able to call C++ code. Edited question. It's a lot of modifications  :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, oh I missed that. I'll give it a try with the correction.

Comment: @ Sachin: How much is a lot? Could this process be automated somehow with a sequence of regex replaces? As Jonathan already commented, no C compiler will be able to read arbitrary C++ headers. One class declaration and your done. Linking will pose yet another barrier. If you don't want to convert to C++ your headers at least should be valid C. What remains then is the linking problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, that still leaves me with an error. I've edited the question. Please see.

Comment: @jacdeh, it's possible to automate it, yes, but I feel it's a little too complicated if it is otherwise possible to make compilation a little lax and get it to work.

Comment: You are still showing `-Wa, -q` with a space.  The x-ref'd question shows `-Wa,-q` without a space.  You have to be very, very careful.  I make no promises that getting this right _will_ fix your problems; but not getting this syntax right definitely won't fix them.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be solving this problem backwards, to me. Every conforming C++ implementation seems to have a compatible C ABI, so C++ projects can use C libraries. Use that to your advantage.

1. Create C libraries containing your C code, and compile them as C code (e.g. `cc -c your_filename.c` will produce a `your_filename.o` object file).
2. Create a C++ project (where you should be able to include all of your C headers, if you design them carefully), and use your linker to link to the `your_filename.o` object files you produced in step 1, when compiling that project.

Comment: Step 1 wasn't possible. Please see my second attempt in the question.

Comment: @SachinHosmani Your 2. attempt states you get an error with `#include <atomic>` , but that isn't C. C has atomic support via  `#include <stdatomic.h>` and you'd likely need to enable C11 to make that available.

Comment: @SachinHosmani So use `<atomic>` in your C++ code to lock access to your C code, or `<stdatomic.h>` (as @nos said) in your C code.

Answer (score 0):

> I put the #includes myself to be able to interact with C++ code from it.

This is where you went wrong.  `#include`ing a C++ header from a `.c` file will never work.

Instead, you need to make header files which are compatible with both C and C++. These files should only contain code in the common subset of C and C++ ; and they should also contain:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { 
#endif

// main header code here

#ifdef __cpluscplus
}
#endif
```

so that the C++ units including this header create calls using the C ABI.

In this header , you can declare some functions that will do the interacting with the C++ code which your C files require. And you can implement those functions in a new C++ source file which you write.