# Does homebrew GCC, or any other way of getting GCC on mac work with AVX out of the box?

Tags: homebrew, gcc

if someone reading this question has a minute or two, might test the build of the following code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <x86intrin.h>
// some compiler feature tests used by makefile

typedef uint8_t vector_8_16 __attribute__ ((vector_size(16)));

static const vector_8_16 key16 = { 7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,
     15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8};

int main() {
  vector_8_16 a = key16;
  vector_8_16 b, c;

  b = reinterpret_cast<vector_8_16>(_mm_shuffle_pd(a, a, 1));
  c = _mm_xor_si128(b, a);
  c = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(b, a);
  c = _mm_andnot_si128(c, a);
  return c[2] & 0;
}
```

with the following invocation:

```
gcc -std=c++11 -march=corei7-avx -flax-vector-conversions test.cc
```

At the moment, I tried gcc5 from this site: http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ but it just doesn't work:

```
 /var/folders/d8/m9xrbkrs2tj3x6xw_h0nmkn40000gn/T//ccXbpcH7.s:10:no such instruction: `vmovdqa LC0(%rip), %xmm0'
 /var/folders/d8/m9xrbkrs2tj3x6xw_h0nmkn40000gn/T//ccXbpcH7.s:11:no such instruction: `vmovaps %xmm0, -16(%rbp)'
 /var/folders/d8/m9xrbkrs2tj3x6xw_h0nmkn40000gn/T//ccXbpcH7.s:12:no such instruction: `vmovapd -16(%rbp), %xmm1'
 /var/folders/d8/m9xrbkrs2tj3x6xw_h0nmkn40000gn/T//ccXbpcH7.s:13:no such instruction: `vmovapd -16(%rbp), %xmm0'
 /var/folders/d8/m9xrbkrs2tj3x6xw_h0nmkn40000gn/T//ccXbpcH7.s:14:no such instruction: `vshufpd $1, %xmm1,%xmm0,%xmm0'
```

A few years ago, I managed to get gcc 4.7 working, after building from source, and replacing the assembler in `/usr/bin/as` with the one from gcc. But that endeavour took some days, and I'm not sure if it works with the current OSX and Xcode tools versions. I suspect this one has similar problems, either trying to use the same assembler as the one came with Xcode, and has a misunderstanding with it, or trying to use it's own assembler, which doesn't know about AVX . I'm not sure yet what exactly is the problem, my next hope ( before spending a few days hacking it to use a useful assembler ) is to try the brew GCC package.

Or, if anyone knows an easy way to bring GCC with AVX to life on mac OS X, I'm happy to hear about it.

Note: clang I can already use, this question is specifically about GCC

==EDIT==

After a lot of searching, I found the same issue answered here, with a solution that works for me:
[How to use AVX/pclmulqdq on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840207/how-to-use-avx-pclmulqdq-on-mac-os-x-lion/10147915)

Sorry for another duplicate question.
Nice talking to myself.
Out