# AVX and newer intrinsics with GCC on Mac; what assembler would one need?

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, intrinsics

I have been tweaking GCC 6.3.0 to get it to use the libc++ runtime instead of libstdc++ so that g++ can be used without worrying about C++ runtime incompatibilities:

https://github.com/RJVB/macstrop/tree/master/lang/gcc6

The tweak works, I can build and run KDE software using g++ against Qt5 and KF5 frameworks (and everything else) built with various clang versions.

What doesn't work is generating code that uses AVX and presumably most or all newer intrinsic instructions.

This is not a new issue that's never been invoked on here; it's answered here for instance: [How to use AVX/pclmulqdq on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840207/how-to-use-avx-pclmulqdq-on-mac-os-x/10147915#10147915)

Evidently one can configure gcc to call the linked script instead of the actual `as` executable.

But can gcc not be configured to use another assembler altogether, like nasm, and would that solve this issue?

Comment: You already seem aware of the option `--with-as=...` for gcc's configure. I doubt it works with nasm, but did you try? Doesn't your mac provide something like llvm-as to access the llvm assembler directly? And if not, what's wrong with configuring gcc to use that script as assembler?

Comment: No, I didn't try, mainly because GCC is a bit too expensive to do experimental builds with when there is reason to believe it won't work anyway - and that's exactly what googling suggests. I would have tried anyway (hoping that the GCC build will use the same assembler and thus fail early if indeed nasm isn't supported) but I found another solution that seems to be working.

Comment: I have llvm-as, but invoking it directly instead of [g]as is not trivial because it has a completely different front-end. What *seems* to be working for now is this wrapper: https://github.com/RJVB/macstrop/blob/master/devel/gccas/files/gccas.sh (installed without the suffix and with @CLANG@ replaced with my MacPorts clang-4.0 binary). This invokes the clang assembler through the clang front-end, and that provides support for the argument compatibility. I *presume* that this calls llvm-as behind the scenes but that's not evident even with -v .